# progress bar for reading lines in text file

Tags: python, progress-bar, progress, text-files

I'm reading lines form  in a text file and then performing actions per line. Due to the size of the text file and the time of each action 500 => seconds. I would like to be able to view the progress but not sure where to start.

Here is an example script I'm using, how would write that for this?

```
import os

tmp = "test.txt"
f = open(tmp,'r')

for i in f:
    ip = i.strip()
    os.system("ping " + ip + " -n 500")

f.close()
```

test.txt:

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.2.1.1
10.2.1.1
```

Comment: @nightcracker Sorry but I'm lost. the 500 = to the packet count from the ping -n option. How would the import time be helpful?

Comment: The problem is, to measure progress (in terms of lines processed) you need to find the total number of lines in the file.  Or you could possibly get the size of the file and use that to generate a statistic.  Either way, you need to find the 'total amount' of processing to be done, and then each iteration through the loop you know you are `100*current_iteration/total_iterations`% of the way done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a handy module: [`progress_bar`](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2010/01/python-command-line-progress-bar-with.html).

It's short and simple enough; read the source for ideas on implementing your own.

Here's a very simple piece of code that, I hope, makes things clearer:

```
import time, sys

# The print statement effectively treats '\r' as a newline, 
# so use sys.stdout.write() and .flush() instead ...
def carriage_return_a():
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()

# ... or send a terminal control code to non-windows systems
# (this is what the `progress_bar` module does)
def carriage_return_b():
    if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win'):
        print '\r'
    else:
        print chr(27) + '[A'

bar_len = 10
for i in range(bar_len + 1):
    # Generate a fixed-length string of '*' and ' ' characters
    bar = ''.join(['*'] * i + [' '] * (bar_len - i))

    # Insert the above string and the current value of i into a format
    # string and print, suppressing the newline with a comma at the end
    print '[{0}] {1}'.format(bar, i),

    # Write a carriage return, sending the cursor back to the beginning
    # of the line without moving to a new line. 
    carriage_return_a()

    # Sleep
    time.sleep(1)
```

As others have observed, you still need to know the total number of lines in the file in order to have a very meaningful progress bar. The most straightforward way to do that is to read the whole file to get a line count; but that's rather wasteful.

Incorporating this into a simple class isn't too hard... now you can create the progress bar and `update()` it whenever the value of interest changes.

```
class SimpleProgressBar(object):
    def __init__(self, maximum, state=0):
        self.max = maximum
        self.state = state

    def _carriage_return(self):
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def _display(self):
        stars = ''.join(['*'] * self.state + [' '] * (self.max - self.state))
        print '[{0}] {1}/{2}'.format(stars, self.state, self.max),
        self._carriage_return()

    def update(self, value=None):
        if not value is None:
            self.state = value
        self._display()

spb = SimpleProgressBar(10)
for i in range(0, 11):
    time.sleep(.3)
    spb.update(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I'm pretty lost and need it to be kinda spelled out.. I have been trying to work out how to implement it or create one but I keep over thinking it and start getting confused..

Comment: Thanks it kinda makes sense, _As others have observed, you still need to know the total number of lines in the file in order to have a very meaningful progress bar_ I figured that part out... its just meshing it together.. Nothing like a little trial and error now..

Answer (score 1):

Another starting point could be the [`progressbar`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.3-dev) module.

You can also download the source code [[here]](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/), inside the tar.gz there's an `example.py` file with some good examples.