# Progress bar when reading a large file (>4GB) in Python

Tags: python, file, file-io, iterator, progress-bar

I'm trying to add a progress bar when reading a large file (around 4Gb). So far I have this:

```
class PercentageFile:

def __init__(self, filename):
    self.size = os.stat(filename)[6]
    self.f = open(filename,"r")
    self.i = self.f.tell()

def __enter__(self):
    return self
def readline(self):
    data = self.f.readline()
    self.i = self.f.tell() 
    return data
def __iter__(self):
    return self
def __next__(self):
    data = self.f.readline()
    if self.i == self.f.tell():
        raise StopIteration
    self.i = self.f.tell()    
    return data
def read(self, size=None):
    if size is None:
        self.i = self.size
        return self.f.read()
    data = self.f.read(size)
    self.i = self.f.tell() 
    return data 
@property
def percentage(self):
    return float(self.i) / self.size * 100.0
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.f.close()
```

The thing is that it's much slower than just reading the file without any progress bar. I'd love to know if there's a way that doesn't take a big hit in performance.

In my system, doing a `for` in a 5kb file takes 0.00013 seconds if created using `open` whereas using my class it takes 0.02038 seconds.

Comment: Removing `self.i` and using `self.f.tell()` instead might speed it up a little.

Comment: Don't read it line by line, read it 100 lines every time. And update the progress bar only when you hit a visual-effective milestone, like 5% or 10% or whatever you set for the bar. Printing to the console is a great time waster.

Comment: I need to perform some operations every line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [progress bar for reading lines in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268652/progress-bar-for-reading-lines-in-text-file)